# Equivalence between different bases of weak convergence of measure

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I am reading Billingsley (1968).Convergence of Probability Measures. In page 236, he mentioned four types of bases for weak topology of probability measure.

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture2]

And when he proved "find within (5) a set of the form (6)."

[image: Picture3]

He wrote that

$\int fdQ<\epsilon+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i}Q\left(F_{i}\right)$

I think this statement is not correct since $F_{i}=\left\{ x\in X:\frac{i}{k}\le f\left(x\right)\right\} $, we have

$\int fdQ \geq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i}i*Q\left(F_{i}\right)$

but since $\frac{1}{k}<\epsilon$, there is no guarantee that

$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i}iQ\left(F_{i}\right)<\epsilon+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i}Q\left(F_{i}\right)$

In this case, I don't think the proof work. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is (2.2) here?