# Prokhorov Metric and Weak Topology of Measure

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $X$ be separable metric space and $\mathscr{M}\left(X\right)$ be the space of all probability measures on $X$ and $d_{P}$ are Prohorov metric on $\mathscr{M}\left(X\right)$. We denote $\mu_{n}\Rightarrow\mu$ if $\mu_{n}$ converges to $\mu$ weakly. It is well known that

$\mu_{n}\Rightarrow\mu\Longleftrightarrow d_{P}\left(\mu_{n},\mu\right)\rightarrow 0$

However, in many books (like Billingsley (1999).Convergence of Probability Measures), they just conclude that the weak topology on $\mathscr{M}\left(X\right)$ can be induced by $d_{P}$. If the weak topology on $\mathscr{M}\left(X\right)$ is metrizable, we can make sure that this statement is true since topology is determined by convergence in metric space.

But we do not have the result that the weak topology on $\mathscr{M}\left(X\right)$ is metrizable. (I know this statement is true, but I don't know how to prove it.)

So my question is how to prove that the weak topology on $\mathscr{M}\left(X\right)$ can be induced by $d_{P}$? Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Theorem 5 , p.238 of Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures.

Comment: I see. Thanks for pointing me out. You mean the 1968 edition of Convergence of Probability Measures. But I am stuck in the proof of Theorem 3, p.236. Could you please see another post of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313124/equivalence-between-different-bases-of-weak-convergence-of-measure